# Python JSON parse from tcp socket

Tags: python, json, tcpsocket

I'm new to python and i'm stuck with a program that should receive json from tcp socket and forward it to http with simple http server. With the code below i am getting following error  `Other error occurred: 'length'` I am assuming it has something to do with dictionary or key in it since i am trying to set tcp buffer size from received json(it has 'length' before actual data). Example `{"length": 203} {"agent_version":3.09,"build_version":"Agent/3.09 (ubuntu; x86_64; conntrack; netlink; dns-cache; plugins; tcmalloc; inotify; regex) no/2.9.0 JSON/1.90","json_version":1.9,"type":"agent_hello"} {"length": 484}`

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import http.server
from logging import exception
import socketserver
import json
import socket


PORT = 8000
buff_size = 219
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('10.10.10.10', 2100))

class MyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    global do_rcv, data, qdata
    def do_rcv():
        global buff_size, data, qdata
        qdata = []
        while True:
            try:
                data = s.recv(buff_size).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
                data += data
                for i in data:
                    i = str('[' + str(i) + ']')
                    i = str(i).replace('}{', '},{')
                    i = str(i).replace('\n', '')
                    qdata = json.loads(i)
                    buff_size = qdata[-1]['length']
                    buff_size = buff_size + 16
                if not data:
                    s.close()
                    return
            #except KeyError:
                #pass
            except Exception as err:
                print(buff_size)
                print(qdata)
                print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
                s.close()
                return
                
    
    def do_GET(self):

        do_rcv()
        output_data = []
        # - request -
        
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        #print('content_length:', content_length)
        
        if content_length:
            input_json = self.rfile.read(content_length)
            input_data = json.loads(input_json)
        else:
            input_data = None
            
        print(input_data)
        
        # - response -
        
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/json')
        self.end_headers()
        
        output_data += qdata
        output_json = json.dumps(output_data)
        
        self.wfile.write(output_json.encode('utf-8'))


Handler = MyHandler

try:
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
        print(f"Starting http://0.0.0.0:{PORT}")
        httpd.allow_reuse_address = True
        httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopping by Ctrl+C")
    httpd.server_close()  # to resolve problem `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`
    s.close() 
except Exception:
    print("Stopping by other exception")
    httpd.server_close()
```

Comment: Raise the `err` to see the full description of it.

Comment: @MohsenDehghankar erros is KeyError: 'length'. just fyi this is continuous stream of json data

Comment: You have lots of problems here, eg. what is data+=data. ?

Comment: Any reason you are duplicating data? (`data += data`). You should print `i` right before `qdata = json.loads(i)`.

Comment: i saw somewhere that `data += data` should be there because i am using tcp socket

Comment: how do you know `buff_size` is enought to hold the whole data? (you example string has 226 characteres)

Comment: `i saw somewhere that data += data should be there` non sense

Comment: You meant: data += s.recv( ...

Comment: @JuanR `buff_size` is not holding whole data, just the bytes length of the data that is coming

Comment: @quamrana `data += s.recv(...` is not going to work since it throws an error saying that data is not defined

Comment: @JuanR after printing `i` before `json.load` i get this: `[{"length": 203}]
----------------------------------------------------
[{"agent_version":3.09,"build_version":"Agent/3.09 (ubuntu; x86_64; conntrack; netlink; dns-cache; plugins; tcmalloc; inotify; regex) no/2.9.0 JSON/1.90","json_version":1.9,"type":"agent_hello"}]
----------------------------------------------------
Other error occurred: 'length'
----------------------------------------`

Comment: Yes, whatever, just delete data+=data

Comment: @quamrana i deleted it as soon as you mentioned it

Comment: @quamrana Unfortunately, no. Now i get this
`219
[{"length": 481}]
----------------------------------------------------
219
[{"cpu_cores":2,"cpu_system":4.190586,"cpu_system_prev":4.173127,"cpu_user":7.578414,"cpu_user_prev":7.529772,"dhc_size":353,"dhc_status":true,"flow_count":153,"flow_count_prev":164,"maxrss_kb":139416,"ma]
----------------------------------------------------
497
Other error occurred: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 202 (char 201)
----------------------------------------` which means buffer is not set correctly. numbers 219 and 497 are buffer length